# Subtotals and total keeping the details

Tags: mysql

I have a table with invoices:

```
invoice_num, customer_ID, usd
1              A          15.2
2              B           3.6
3              A         105.1
4              C           6.0
```

I need a report showing all the records (invoices) and adding a subtotal per customer. I know how to do it if I just show the total per customer (with GROUP BY customer_ID and WITH ROLLUP) but I need to keep the details, so I can't group the lines.
The desired output is:

```
invoice_num  customer_ID   usd
1              A          15.2
3              A         105.1
Total customer A         120.3
2              B           3.6
Total customer B           3.6
4              C           6.0
Total customer C           6.0
Total customers          129.9
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Also group on `invoice_num`:

```
SELECT   invoice_num, customer_ID, SUM(usd)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY customer_ID, invoice_num WITH ROLLUP
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ace9b1/1/0).